# angular-cli 6: How to supress build-progress of e2e-task?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

In angular-cli 1.x there was an option `--progress=false` for the `ng e2e`-task. How can I achieve this now with `angular-cli 6`?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but what I can say is from `angular-cli` v1.x to v6.x one of the main focuses was changes to the CLI. Many of the command line flags that use to be present were removed and are now to be set in their respected conf files like `angular.json` or `protractor.conf.js`. The `--progress` flag is a Protractor flag so you may want to start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. In `angular.json` you have to set the option `"progress": false` in the `projects/your-app/serve/options`-section.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-app:build",
            "progress": false
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
      }
    },
    "your-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "your-app:serve"
          },
        },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "your-app"
}
```